# How to separate many dataframes from one excel Sheet Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm using an excel sheet with many different dataframes on it. I'd like to import those dataframes but separately. For now When i import the excel_file with pandas, it creates one single dataframe full of blanks where the dataframe are delimited. How can I create a different dataframe for each on of them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `pandas.read_excel()` function, you can simply use the `usecols` parameter to specify which columns you want to include in each dataframe. Only downside would be you'd need to do a `read_excel` call for each of the dataframes you want to read in.

Comment: First of all thanks for taking the time to answer my question. But what if they share de same columns in the excel file and they're just below one another separated by two blank rows? Thanks again